# Declare variable for ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

i have small problem with ngModel.

I'm creating object declaration in ts file:

```
 public descriptorSelected: DescriptorCreateSelected = {
    location: '',
    methodType: '',
    securityLevel: '',
    provider: '',
    inputParameters: {
      documentType: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      optionalDocumentType: '',
      preferedLanguage: '',
      redirectUrlDefined: '',
      organizationName: '',
      organizationVat: '',
      certificationMode: ''
    }
  };
```

interface looks like this:

```
export interface DescriptorCreateSelected {
  location?: string;
  methodType?: string;
  securityLevel?: string;
  provider?: string;
  inputParameters?: DescriptorInputParametersSelected

}
```

I want to use this object "descriptorSelected" in HTML file to bind value from inputs.
Declarations with "location", "methodType" works fine.
When I want to bind variable from "inputParameters{}", eg: "inputParameters.documentType" I see error:

```
error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<select name="inputParametersDocumentType" [(ngModel)]="descriptorSelected.inputParameters.documentType">
```

What is wrong?

And additional question - if I'm using interface with object model, do I always have to declare variable before I will be able to bind it?

Answer (score -1):

Because `inputParameters` property is declared as optional. Remove `?` to make it required.

There is no reason to declare all properties as optional if you initialize variable in constructor with certain values.

Comment: @Mike S. you are correct! Anyway, if interface is declared somewhere else then at least `inputParameters` property must be made required in this particular use. Or `(ngModelChange)` will try to create property `documentType` on `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

remove ? for **inputParameters** to make it required

```
export interface DescriptorCreateSelected {
  location?: string;
  methodType?: string;
  securityLevel?: string;
  provider?: string;
  inputParameters?: DescriptorInputParametersSelected // you must remove ? 

}
```